# How an ORM manages two aggregation of the same type

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, relational-database, software-design

I have a class `User` that has some (almost all physical) details like: `hair color, eyes color, height, ...`, and preferences about his ideal partner regarding same details.
So, in OO world i have (java-like code):

```
class User {
    private String name;
    ...
    private Collection<Detail> details; 
    private Collection<Detail> partner_preferences;
}

class UserDetail {
    private User user;
    private Detail detail;
    private String value;
}

class Detail {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

I will use an ORM to map my objects into a relational database; now the question arises is: how an ORM manages a situation like this? Is it enough smart to add a discriminator or something similar?

Probably this project will be implemented with PHP/Doctrine

Comment: Are youwanting different classes for each detail?  DetailHairColor, DetailHeight etc?  If so, Doctrine 2 does indeed support this.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Nope, I just want to store and retrieve correctly `details` and `partner_preferences`. eg: User has brown hair and prefers partner with blonde hair: `details = { hair : blonde }, partner_details = { hair : blonde }`, how doctrine doesn't get confused by these two collections? (same user, same details but different fields)

Answer (score 0):

The Detail class sounds like a value object, which Doctrine does not support (natively) at the moment, but you can do it with a bit of userland code.

If you don't handle your Detail class as a value object, but like a normal entity, then this problem becomes a classic many-to-many relation, which is a very basic feature of ORMs, I'd be surprised if you found one that does not support this.